# Nav bar wont lay over top slider

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new to programming. I'm using bootstrap and I'm trying to get the Nav menu to overlay over the slider at the top of the website.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or point me in the right direction? 
Here is a link to the site on codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MwLBKv

HTML

```
<!-- bootstarp-css -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
  <!-- FontAwesome   
-->
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--// bootstarp-css -->
<!-- css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<!--// css -->
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<!--fonts-->
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,800,700,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<!--/fonts-->
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>
     new WOW().init();
</script>
<!--start-smoth-scrolling-->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/move-top.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/easing.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                    event.preventDefault();
                    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},900);
                });
            });
        </script>
<!--start-smoth-scrolling-->

</head>

<body>
    <!-- banner -->
    <div id="home" class="banner a-banner">

        <!-- container -->

                <div class="container">
                <div class="head-logo">
                    <a href="index.html"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ6FfLzPB1MpLiIxrIapoSbEf0PFvTjQ3TbcLrQCijCN68LfWZi" alt="" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="top-nav">
                    <ul class="nav1">
                        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="contact.html">Contact<i><img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png" alt=""/></i></a></li>
                        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="services.html">Services<i><img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png" alt=""/></i></a></li>
                        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom"><a href="about.html">About<i><img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png" alt=""/></i></a></li>
                        <li class="hvr-sweep-to-bottom active"><a href="index.html">Home<i><img src="http://demo.chimerathemes.com/wp-content/themes/apppress/images/icons/included/color.png" alt=""/></i></a></li>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                    </ul>
                    <!-- script-for-menu -->
                             <script>
                               $( "span.menu" ).click(function() {
                                 $( "ul.nav1" ).slideToggle( 300, function() {
                                 // Animation complete.
                                  });
                                 });
                            </script>
                    <!-- /script-for-menu -->
        </div>

        </div>

<!-- car -->    

<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
      <div class="slide-1">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="hero">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Recovery</h1>        
            <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <div class="see-button">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg see-button hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="about.html" role="button">See More</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-2">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="hero">        
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Equiped for any Job</h1>        
            <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
        </hgroup>       
        <div class="see-button">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg see-button hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="about.html" role="button">See More</a>
        </div>      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item slides">
      <div class="slide-3">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="hero">        
        <hgroup>
            <h1>Batman</h1>        
            <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
        </hgroup>
        <div class="see-button">
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg see-button hvr-shutter-out-horizontal" href="about.html" role="button">See More</a>
        </div>      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
<!-- car -->
</div>

<!-- //container -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
body{
    background:#fff;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
body a {
  transition: 0.5s all;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s all;
  -o-transition: 0.5s all;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s all;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s all;
}
.banner{
  background: url(../images/banner2.jpg) no-repeat 0px 0px #eeece9;
  min-height: 855px;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}
.head-logo{
  float: left;
}
.head-logo a {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 3.5em;
}
.top-nav{
  float: right;
  width: 70%;
}
.top-nav ul{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
.top-nav ul  li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
  margin-right: .4em;
  display:block;
  float: right;
  line-height:38px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  position:relative;
}
.top-nav ul  li.active{
    background: #5abc5e;
}
.top-nav ul li a{
color: #FFF;
  font-size: 18px;
  margin-right: .4em;
  float: left;
  padding: 3em 0em 3em 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
  width: 79%;
}
.top-nav ul li a i{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 1em;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: italic;
}
.top-nav ul li a:hover{
    text-decoration:none;
}

/********************************/
/*       Fade Bs-carousel       */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li {
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #f39c12;
    border-color: #f39c12;
    opacity: .7;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li.active {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/********************************/
/*          Hero Headers        */
/********************************/
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
              transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}
.hero h1 {
    font-size: 6em;    
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;    
}

/********************************/
/*            Overlay           */
/********************************/
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #080d15;
    opacity: .3;
}

/********************************/
/*       Slides backgrounds     */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
  background-image: url(../images/banner2.jpg); 
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(../images/squad.jpg);
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  background-image: url(../images/roadside.jpg);
}

/********************************/
/*          Media Queries       */
/********************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 980px){
    .hero { width: 980px; }    
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    .hero h1 { font-size: 4em; }    
}

/* Sweep To Bottom */
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom {
  display: inline-block;                                           
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
  -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -ms-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
        -o-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
    -o-transition-property: color;
  -moz-transition-property: color;
  -ms-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
    -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #5abc5e;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
    -o-transform: scaleY(0);
  -moz-transform: scaleY(0);
  -ms-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0;
  transform-origin: 50% 0;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
    -o-transition-property: transform;
  -moz-transition-property: transform;
  -ms-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
      -o-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -moz-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -ms-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
        -o-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -moz-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  -ms-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-bottom:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-bottom:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

.banner-bottom-grids{
    margin: 5em 0;
}
.banner-bottom-left{
  padding: 0;
  padding-left: 0 !important;
  padding-right: 0 !important;
  margin: 0;
}
.banner-bottom-left h3{
  color: #000;
  font-size: 37px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.banner-bottom-left h5{
  color: #969696;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 1em 0;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}
.banner-bottom-left h5 span{
    display:block;
}
.banner-bottom-left p{
color: #333333;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.8em;
  font-weight: 600;
}
.banner-bottom-right img{
    width:100%;
}
.see-button{
  margin-top: 1em;
}
.see-button a{
  font-size: 14px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 1em 4em;
  outline: none;
  background: #393939;
  border: none !important;
  border-radius:0;
  }
.jumbotron.banner-bottom-left {
  background: none;
}
/*------------------ Slider Part starts Here----------*/
#slider2,
#slider3 {
  box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.rslides_tabs {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.25);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.3), inset 0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,1.0);
  font-size: 18px;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 auto 50px;
  max-width: 540px;
  padding: 10px 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
.rslides_tabs li {
  display: inline;
  float: none;
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.rslides_tabs a {
  width: auto;
  line-height: 20px;
  padding: 9px 20px;
  height: auto;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline;
}
.rslides_tabs li:first-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
.rslides_tabs .rslides_here a {
  background: rgba(255,255,255,.1);
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.events {
  list-style: none;
}
.callbacks_container {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
.callbacks {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.callbacks li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.callbacks img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
}
.callbacks .caption {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-shadow: none;
    color: #fff;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    margin: 0;
    max-width: none;
    top: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
.callbacks_nav {
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
    top: 52%;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index: 3;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 61px;
    width: 55px;
    background: transparent url("../images/themes.png") no-repeat left top;
    margin-top: -65px;
}
.callbacks_nav:active {
  opacity: 1.0;
}
.callbacks_nav.next {
  left: auto;
  background-position: right top;
  right: 0;
}
#slider3-pager a {
  display: inline-block;
}
#slider3-pager span{
  float: left;
}
#slider3-pager span{
    width:100px;
    height:15px;
    background:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    border-radius:30em;
    opacity:0.6;
}
#slider3-pager .rslides_here a {
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius:30em;
  opacity:1;
}
#slider3-pager a {
  padding: 0;
}
#slider3-pager li{
    display:inline-block;
}
.rslides {
  position: relative;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.rslides li {
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
.rslides li{
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
.rslides img {
  height: auto;
  border: 0;
  width:100%;
}
.callbacks_tabs{
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 78%;
  z-index: 999;
  left: 45%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
.slider-top{
    text-align: center;
    padding:10em 0;
}
.slider-top h1{
    font-weight:700;
    font-size:48px;
    color:#010101;
}
.slider-top p{
    font-weight:400;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:1em 7em;
    color:#010101;
}
.slider-top ul.social-slide{
    display:inline-flex;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do?  Are you talking about having the collapsed nav (hamburger) show up in place of the chunky menu items when the screen gets smaller?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by overlay. [This](http://imgur.com/h7kxPrh) is what I'm seeing. What *should* the menu look like?

Comment: I'm trying to get the menu and the logo to be on top of the slider rather than over/ on top of it.
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `position: absolute;` and `z-index: 5;` to your nav `.container`. I would recommend you use the `.container` class on your page container and use some of bootstraps nav classes to build your nav bar.

Comment: I'm trying to get the menu and the logo to be on top of the slider rather than over/ on top of it. Thanks for your help

Comment: I simply added the code I wrote in my answer. Adding position: absolute; allows the navbar and slider to overlap and adding z-index: 5; to the container changes the "height" it show up on the page so it can be clicked instead of showing behind the slider. Check out the bootstrap website for info on how to more effectivly use its classes, also this. http://learnlayout.com/position.html